# How to implement 2 step booking process without backend with React and Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on React & Firestore app for simple restaurant management. I don't use any backend. Now I'm implementing booking process based on 2 steps:

1. On route `/book-table` user fills the form with data, which is send to **Firestore** (Cloud functions validation for email, number of guests etc.)
2. On route `/review-booking` user verifies if he want to change submitted data or confirm reservation.

Is that correct way of doing that? I'm afraid that second - review booking step forces me to make another unnecessary(?) Firestore call to:

- update data of existing booking (is passing docID in frontend safe?)
- ... or set field confirmed to true

[Here](https://alkinoos-taverna.netlify.com/book-table) is live version Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's a possible option.

Another possible option is to create [props](https://itnext.io/what-is-props-and-how-to-use-it-in-react-da307f500da0) or a list and save the information of the reservation there.

Then, you can pass to review-booking component the properties from the previous component, if the user confirms the reservation, you can save to firestore and if the user wants to edit the booking , you can do the same as before ( pass the properties to the book-table component ).

If you want to edit a confirmed booking, then you've to  make a call to firestore.

Let me know it it works for you.

Comment: I was also thinking about sticking with frontend validation only in first step '/book-table', then send it via Redux to '/review-booking' component, and then try to send it to Firestore. It will require to redesign the '/review-booking' component to have form with submit to Firestore once is on edit mode.